Are there any Gatherer rulings with an “if somehow” that can’t ever be met?
I’m hope this isn’t too obscure. It came as a curiosity. Just how precautionary is WOTC on gatherer rulings?
I’m talking about Gatherer rulings phrasings on cards such as Spark Double like:

If Spark Double somehow enters the battlefield at the same time as another permanent, it can't become a copy of that permanent. You may choose only a creature or planeswalker that's already on the battlefield

Rules Lawyer

If you somehow control a creature that's attached to another permanent, that creature can stay attached. It can attack and block, even if another creature is carrying it. Similarly, if you control a permanent that isn't an Aura, an Equipment, or a Fortification, it can stay attached to whatever you manage to get it attached to. Strange. (704.5p)


One thing to remember is that Gatherer rulings - and in particular the exact wording used in rulings - are pretty arbitrary. The wording used for a particular ruling, and even the presence or absence of a ruling, is just what Wizards' editorial department felt like that day. I wouldn't read anything into whether "somehow" is or isn't in a Gatherer ruling.

Not an "if somehow" ruling, but this rule currently has no way of happening: "104.3f If a player would both win and lose the game simultaneously, that player loses the game"

I've looked through a lot of cards that have "somehow" rulings on Gatherer, and they range from "easily achieved" to "incredibly convoluted". Some of the ones that require a bit of work include:

Abilities that rely on a previous choice, and a ruling that says "if somehow the choice was not made". For example, the third chapter ability of Medomai's Prophecy refers to a card name chosen by its second chapter, which could be nullified by countering the trigger of the second chapter.

Crystalline Resonance has two rulings about turning into an Aura while somehow already being attached to a creature, or a planeswalker while somehow already having loyalty counters, but you can make both of those happen (e.g. by copying a Gliding Licid, and by turning a Gideon planeswalker into a creature then using Fate Transfer to shift the loyalty counters across).

I thought maybe Gaea's Revenge would at least be an example where the ruling was impossible at the time (2010), since it referenced "somehow" having a green Equipment where the first such example was Wolfrider's Saddle from Core Set 2020, but 2008 brought Shadowmoor and with it Painter's Servant.

Predatory Urge has a ruling if it somehow becomes attached to another creature while the tap ability it bestows is still resolving, but Aura Finesse among others allows for instant-speed Aura moving.


There is one card that requires a lot of checking of corner cases, but whose "somehow" still proves doable:

Hungry Lynx has protection from Rats which includes "Auras and Equipment that are somehow Rats" and "spells that are somehow Rats".

There are some Kindred Instant spells with Changeling (thanks, Blades of Velis Vel) that will count as Rats, so that second "somehow" is definitely achievable.
The question then is whether it's possible to have an Aura or Equipment that is somehow a Rat. Let's go through the possibilities:

Licids and Reconfigure creatures like Simian Sling stop being creatures (and hence lose their subtypes) when they become an Aura or Enchantment, so even granting one of them Changeling wouldn't cause them to ever be a Rat once they've attached to something (although relevant to Hungry Lynx, their abilities are activated while they're still creatures so if you make them Rats then you can't directly attach them to the Lynx).

Per rules 301.5c and 303.4d, if an Aura or Equipment is also a creature, then it immediately detaches itself (and in the case of Auras, goes to the graveyard) as a state-based action, so you can't animate one and then turn it into a Rat.

Finally, though, it is possible to have a Kindred Equipment like Diviner's Wand, and through the use of Artificial Evolution change its type to "Kindred Artifact - Rat Equipment", thus making it unable to target Hungry Lynx. Similarly, Artificial Evolution can change Lignify's subtype as it resolves, proving that we can have a Rat Aura.


So, in the end, I believe the answer is no - every ruling that uses the word "somehow" appears to have a situation where it can happen, as obscure as it may be.

If I could +2 I would for all your work. I somehow :) thought they would make these rulings without thinking of all the specific edge cases, but you’ve shown they really have all the edge cases in mind already
